# Count the primitive polynomials of degree $d$ over $F_{2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, finite-fields, solution-verification

I am trying to solve an exercise, where i have to determine the number of the primitive polynomials of degree $10$ over the finite field $F_{2}$.

My approach was using the formula $\frac{\varphi (p^{d}-1)}{d}$, where $p$ is the number of the elements of the finite field, $d$ the degree and $\varphi$ is the Euler totient function.
So, i get $\frac{\varphi (2^{10}-1)}{10}=\frac{600}{10}=60$.

Do you agree with this solution? I would be glad to read your comments and remarks.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd say this is correct, but it needs more explanation.

Comment: Looks good to me. Presumably some facts (e.g. that formula) have been covered in your course/book. If not, then it is a good exercise to prove that formula!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $q$ is a prime power, then the number of primitive monic degree $d$ polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$ is indeed
$$
\frac{φ(q^d − 1)}{d}.
$$
And primitive polynomials are necessarily irreducible. We have $99$ monic irreducible
polynomials of degree $10$ over $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$, and $60$ of them are primitive.

Comment: Yes, i used the same formulas. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. The formula for the number of monic irreducible polynomials, which I have used is $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)q^{n/d}$.